# Saving/Loading Plist Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I'm trying something super simple to try to save and load from a Plist, but it is not working.  I would greatly appreciate if someone would like to look over my code and let me know what is wrong.

```
- (IBAction)testSave:(id)sender {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistLocation = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistLocation];

    [plistDict setObject:@"test" forKey:@"test"];
    [plistDict writeToFile:plistLocation atomically: YES];
}

- (IBAction)testLoad:(id)sender {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistLocation = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistLocation];

    testField.text = [plistDict objectForKey:@"test"];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Define "not working". Does the code compile? Does it run? What happens? What messages (if any) do you get?

Comment: The code returns a blank field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`To write the File : You are making mistake here`

```
- (IBAction)testSave:(id)sender {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistLocation = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

    // Declare Dictionary Object
    NSMutableDictionary* plistDict;

    // Check if plist file exist or not, if EXIST load data from it otherwise create new
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistLocation])
        plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistLocation];
    else
        plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [plistDict setObject:@"test" forKey:@"test"];
    [plistDict writeToFile:plistLocation atomically: YES];
}
```

`Your Code for Reading is Correct` Try it. Good Luck.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have data.plist in your Document Directory .In order to find that find out the value stored in plistLocation. Follow the path,and then verify if you really have the data.plist in there.

Hope it Helps!!!